# Active Admin with custom filter on a non-table attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin, ransack

collection: `users`

attributes: `name, phone_no, email`

```
ActiveAdmin.register User do
   filter 'period', as: :date_range, label: 'From - To'
end
```

Above code works well for a date range

HOWEVER, Below active admin code doesn't work

```
ActiveAdmin.register User do
   filter 'preference', as: :string
end
```

Error raised is:

```
undefined method `preference_contains' for Ransack::Search<class: User, base: Grouping <combinator: and>>:Ransack::Search
```

Both `period` and `preference` are not attributes in the user table. I want to be able to have preference work as a free text box search param, which i'll use in the controller to derive to a data and then render records.

Please help

Comment: How is `preference` defined?

Comment: `preference` is not defined anywhere just like `period` is not defined. They are not a part of the collection "`User`"

Comment: What you want to filter with `preference `?

Comment: There are some articles on custom filters linked from the wiki (https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/wiki#index-pages-filters-and-scopes) You will need to add more details to get an answer here, however.

Answer (score 0):

If `preference` is another table, you can filter by `preference` attributes like this:

`filter :preference_attribute, as: :string`

For example, if `preference` table has an attribute called `link`, you can do this:

`filter :preference_link, as: :string`